# Is there a way in google sheets to have the date:time format changed automatically on imported data?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The format in question is `2023-02-13T16:39:32.000Z`.
Currently the format tool isn't able to do this for me in sheets, and this is data coming from an outside source so I can't change it in the source.
How can I format the column so I don't have to go and change all by hand.
Looking to have date formatted to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Already tried using the format tool in sheets and it's keeps deleting all of the data any time I enter a new format type.

Comment: You may try `=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"T"),1,1),"mm/dd/yyyy")` or `=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"T"),1,1)` then format your column as desired date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula in another column and format to your liking

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"T..+$"," ")+0
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]